# Adding text formatting to the comment section in my NodeJS app

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, formatting

I want to add an interactive text formmating "area" to the form where users post comments on my nodejs app.
I tried to look for something like that on google for half an hour, I'm not sure
what's the name of something like this? i tried looking for comment section formatting area.
I'm talking about a bar just like the one on stackoverflow - 
[image: This is the functionality i want to add]

So I'm wondering if there is something that's already built and I can add it to my project like an npm package? or another js project that i can install on my site? (free or not).
I'm guessing that it's possible to make it only with js but I don't think my jsskills are good enough right now.
Also, if that's possible - I want it to make the text bold (for example) when the user is writing the comment instead of putting those brackets [b] [/b] in the text area for him to see.

another question on that topic - lets say i only want to allow the users to use bold tagging and not h3 tags or underline tags, how can i check that the input the user had entered matches my rules? Do i have to use regex? I've installed Express-sanitizer but i think it only works for script tags.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called WYSIWYG editors. So there are some popular for example

- [Summernote](https://summernote.org/)
- [TinyMCE](https://www.tiny.cloud/)
- [SCEditor](https://www.sceditor.com/)

Check their documentation to integrate to your app.
Regarding validation, it's up to you and depends on your rules. You can use regex if you need it, or any validation package if it works for you.